# Scala: Type mismatch, returns BlockList[Any] instead of BlockList[R]

Tags: scala, generics, generic-collections

Just to get more experience with Scala, and as an experiment, I'm implementing a class that has a `List`-like API, but is implemented as a list of `IndexedSeq` with an index to the first element; `tail` just returns a copy with the index incremented, and prepending `Array`s is O(1), while appending `Array`s is O(m), m = length of list <= number of elements.

I'm running into problems with my function return types. Pretty much every method has the type parameters `[R >: T : ClassManifest, A <: R : ClassManifest]`, `T` being the type parameter of `BlockList`. Sometimes these methods just return others, but in those situations I get an error from Eclipse saying that it was looking for type `BlockList[R]` but found type `BlockList[Any]`. Shouldn't `R` be the lowest common super type of both `T` and `A`? In which case, the second method call should also return `BlockList[R]`, right? What am I not getting? I reflect `ClassManifest` a lot to overcome the problems of type erasure, but I don't know if it's still a problem.

The errors are from the definitions of `|:` and `:|`.

```
import collection.immutable.List
import reflect.ClassManifest
import annotation.tailrec

sealed abstract
class BlockList [+T] extends Seq[T] with Product {
...
}

object EmptyBlock extends BlockList[Nothing] {
...
}

class Build [T: ClassManifest](
private val block: IndexedSeq[T],
private val next: BlockList[T] = EmptyBlock,
private val index: Int = 0
) extends BlockList[T] {
require(!block.isEmpty && index >= 0 && index < block.length)

override def |: [R >: T : ClassManifest, A <: R] (x: A): BlockList[R] =
    Array[R](x) |: this //Return type error here

override def |: [R >: T : ClassManifest, A <: R : ClassManifest]
(blk: IndexedSeq[A]): BlockList[R] =
    if (blk isEmpty) this
    else new Build[R](blk, this)

override def :| [R >: T : ClassManifest, A <: R] (x: A): BlockList[R] =
    this :| Array[R](x) //Return type error here

override def :| [R >: T : ClassManifest, A <: R : ClassManifest]
(blk: IndexedSeq[A]): BlockList[R] = 
    if (blk isEmpty) this
    else new Build[R](block, next :| blk, index) //Type error here

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying that to the smallest possible example that produces the error.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I took your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't R be the lowest common super type of both T and A?

No, because `R` is an upper bound. `R` can be *any* super class of `T`, and the only class that satisfies that bound is `Any`.

Imagine, for instance, that `R` was `AnyRef` -- you could then call methods such as `eq` on it, which would break if an `Int` was passed.

So, while `R` *can* be something lower than `Any` (and probably will be most of the time), at the time you declare it one cannot assume it to be anything lower than `Any`.

However, I think the above has nothing whatsoever to do with your problem. The errors you report appear in these lines, right?

```
Array[R](x) |: this
this :| Array[R](x)
```

The other one also has an `:|` in it. You don't show any implicit conversion from `Array` to `Build`, and none of the `:|` methods take an `Array` as parameter (arrays are not `IndexedSeq`).

So, when you write

```
this :| Array[R](x)
```

This would call `def |: [R1 >: T : ClassManifest, A <: R1] (x: A): BlockList[R1]` (I've changed `R` to `R1` nto to confuse with the `R` in the parameter), where the type of `A` is `Array[R]`, and the only supertype of `T` and `Array[R]` is `Any`, so `R1` has to be `Any`, but that `Any` is different than `R`.

Perhaps, if you called it `this.:|[R, Array[R]](Array[R](x)), it would move things a little further. With the missing definitions that allow`Array` to be passed, I can't predict much else.

Comment: I was under the impression that `Array` get's auto-wrapped to `WrappedArray`, which is itself an `IndexedSeq`. The constructor accepts `Array` arguments so far in the code, so it seems to me that it is getting auto-wrapped sometimes. (Originally `block` was an `Array[T]`, but `Array`'s invariance caused too many problems.) I changed those `Array[R](x)` calls to `(Array[R](x) toIndexedSeq)`, which seemed to solve the problem. Now I'm confused about under which conditions `Array`s are implicitly converted to `WrappedArray`s.